# Stop OpenCL support for a GPU

Tags: opencl, gpu

I have two GPUs installed on my machine. I am working with library which uses OpenCL acceleration that only support one GPU and it is not configurable. I can not tell it which one I want. It seems that this library for some reason chose one of my GPUs that I do not want.

How can I delete/stop/deactivate this GPU from being supported as an OpenCL device?

I want to do this so I get only one supported GPU and the library will be forced to use it.

Note: Any option that contains change or edit the library is available for me.

P.S. I am on Windows 10 with Intel processor and Intel GPU + NVidia GPU

Comment: uninstall its drivers or just delete/rename its opencl dll files and maybe some other files too. Why not query all gpus and let the user pick from ui or let programmer pick it as a function parameter? Maybe disable it from device manager of windows?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows the OpenCL ICD system uses Registry entries to find all of the installed OpenCL platforms.

Solution: Using RegEdit you can backup and then remove the entry for the GPU you do not want to use. The Registry location is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors.

Reference: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/khr/cl_khr_icd.txt